# Exposing the web service using CXF

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf

I have a requirement to expose a webservice using CXF. I am following this easy tutorial [link text](https://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/writing-a-service-with-spring.html) and did the following steps

1. Created a service and an implementation with @WebService annotations
2. Added the standard xml snippet of including cxf.xml and other xmls specified
3. Now I need to deploy this webservice in multiple containers. In a normal web app, I just added the CXF Servlet config but I have another application which is a bespoke framework built on top of Jetty and some handlers/exporters where there is no specific web.xml as such. In such a scenario is there any spring configuration which when declared does the equivalent of this servlet configuration bit?